# List of Images from absolute path in Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1, absolute-path

I am developing windows phone 8.1 application,

I have a URL that is absolute path, and I have to show images that are dynamically changes every time.

How do I show them inside a ListBox?

Here is my XML file:

```
<root> 
  <row> 
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <Name>ABCD</projectName> 
    <isImage>1</isImage> 
  </row> 

 <row> 
   <Id>5678</Id> 
   <Name>PQRS</Name> 
   <isImage>1</isImage>
  </row>
</root>
```

See my XAML code below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Width="480" Height="677" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,59" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Extended">

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White" Height="80" Margin="0,10,0,0">

     <Image x:Name="image1" Source="{Binding isImage}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="70" Width="90" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

      </StackPanel>

   </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

var nodes = doc.Descendants("row").ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
   string newid = nodes[i].Element("Id").Value;

   string uri = "https://www.XYZ.com/abc/getDocument.htm?username=" + name + "&password=" + pwd + "&Id=" + newid;

   List<LIST> list = new List<LIST>();

   list = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
       select new LIST
       {
         Id = query.Element("Id").Value,
         Name = query.Element("Name").Value,
         isImage = uri
       }).ToList();

   listBox1.DataContext = list;

}
```

I am getting only last "Id" of "Counting Nodes", that is the problem.

How should I resolve it, please help me out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are binding every time inside the For Loop, try to bind it once all the elements are added to the List.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
  Your logic
}
listBox1.DataContext = list;
```

Comment: I am getting "six" descendants nodes, so there are "six" nodes of "row". But I am getting only one image six times. I tried your code. @Sajeetharan

Comment: because you are binding the same image!

Comment: Then how to deal with it, I am stuck here for last two days. Please help me out brother. Thanks. @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

See the code below:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
List<LIST> list = new List<LIST>();
var nodes = doc.Descendants("row").ToList();

 for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
 {
    string newid = nodes[i].Element("Id").Value;
    string uri = "https://www.XYZ.com/abc/getDocument.htm?username=" + name + "&password=" + pwd + "&Id=" + newid;

    list.Add(new LIST() { isImage = uri});
 }

 listBox1.DataContext = list;
```

This is working fine and superbly!!